# Shorten and optimize php custom code for wordpress page template and use shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm pretty new to php coding, but i know wordpress for a long time. Also experimenting with bootstrap. I created a new Page Template and modified it a bit. What I'm looking for is to optimize this php code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col kb_landing_left">
    <?php
        global $post; 
        $post = get_post(56); 
        setup_postdata($post);
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page', get_post_format() );
    ?>
</div>
<div class="col -sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col kb_landing_right">
    <?php
        global $post; 
        $post = get_post(1); 
        setup_postdata($post);
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page', get_post_format() );
    ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col kb_landing_right">
    <?php
        global $post; 
        $post = get_post(3); 
        setup_postdata($post);
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page', get_post_format() );
    ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col kb_landing_right">
    <?php
        global $post; 
        $post = get_post(2); 
        setup_postdata($post);
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page', get_post_format() );
    ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's calling for 4 specific post IDs, since i want them to appear on my homepage in a bootsrap grid. I guess this could be done better by using an array?

Any suggestion is very much appreciated! Stay healthy!

Comment: Please do not change the code in the question after you have received a review, read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the anatomy of a shortcode, and how to add and then use them.

```php
add_shortcode('my_custom_shortcode', function ($atts, $content = NULL, $tag = NULL) {
    $defaults = ['a' => 'default A', 'b' => 'default B', 'c' => 'default C'];
    $atts     = shortcode_atts($defaults, $atts, $tag);

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <h2>This is shortcode "<?= $tag ?>"</h2>

    <p><em>With the attributes of:</em></p>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($atts as $key => $value) : ?>
            <li><strong><?= $key ?>:</strong> <?= $value ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <p><em>With the content of:</em></p>
    <?= $content ?: '(Content was not passed to this shortcode)' ?>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

- In order to create a shortcode you need use the `add_shortcode` function

  - It takes two arguments: a `$tag` and a `$callback` (a callback can either be an anonymous function, as used in this example, a string that is the name of the callback function defined elsewhere, or an array of class and method).
  - `$tag` can be whatever you want, just as long as no other shortcode is already using that name. I chose `my_custom_shortcode` for this example
  - `$callback` accepts three arguments `$atts, $content = NULL, $tag = NULL`

    - `$atts` is an array of the arguments the user defined
    - `$content` is any text the user defined inside of a shortcode (`[my_custom_shortcode]This text right here (if applicable)[/my_custom_shortcode]`)
    - `$tag` is the shortcode name, if you are using an anonymous function it will always be identical to the $tag name when adding the shortcode. It can be helpful because you can use the same (non-anonymous) callback function for different shortcodes and just change them slightly depending the the tag name.
- inside the callback you can optionally use the `shortcode_atts` function. It allows you to restrict/expect certain values from the user, set defaults (if not passed by the user), and drop/ignore params that are invalid (as decided by you). I typically will do this, but it's not required.
- you want to return a string in the callback. DON'T echo/display the contents directly to the buffer. That is a common mistake. You can use `ob_start()` to start capturing the output buffer and `ob_get_clean()` to get then clear the buffer when you're done.

Here is how a user (or you) can call a shortcode in code:

```php
// This is the most primitive form, no params or content is passed
// NOTE: just like html, if there is no content, you don't need to close the shortcode tag
echo do_shortcode('[my_custom_shortcode]');

// This example has one param, in this case `b`, passed and content
// NOTE: since you do want to pass content here, you do need to have a closing shortcode tag
echo do_shortcode('[my_custom_shortcode b="some user defined value for B"]The user contents[/my_custom_shortcode]');
```

If you want to call a shortcode from some WYSIWYG/Gutenberg type UI tool in WordPress, you just need the string, like this...

```html
[my_custom_shortcode]

-or-

[my_custom_shortcode b="some user defined value for B"]The user contents[/my_custom_shortcode]
```

...and WordPress with call `do_shortcode` behind the scenes.

**So...**
How would you use it? Well I don't know what's inside your template file you're using for this question, but what's in there would go inside your shortcode callback. Here is your HTML, optimized from the original question

```php
<div class="col kb_landing_left">
    <?= do_shortcode('[my_custom_shortcode post_id="56"]') ?>
</div>
<div class="col -sm-6">
    <?php foreach ([1, 3, 2] as $post_id) : ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col kb_landing_right">
                <?= do_shortcode("[my_custom_shortcode post_id='{$post_id}']") ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

That's it, I would not mess with changing the global $post, it will cause you more problems than it's worth.

Here is how you write the shortcode:

```php
add_shortcode('my_custom_shortcode', function ($atts, $content = NULL, $tag = NULL) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(['post_id' => 0], $atts, $tag);

    if (empty($atts['post_id']) || empty($post = get_post($atts['post_id']))) {
        return ''; // return nothing, a proper post_id was not passed by the user
    }

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <h2>Title: <?= $post->post_title ?></h2>
    <p><?= $content ?: $post->post_excerpt ?></p>
    <p><a href="<?= get_permalink($post->ID) ?>">Read More</a></p>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

In my example, I'm creating a custom shortcode called `my_custom_shortcode`. I'm only accepting a post_id param. If post_id is not passed, or is not a valid id for a post, I exit early with an empty string. If a valid post is found, then I display the Title, content (if passed by user or fallback to the post excerpt), then a Read More link that takes me to that post's url. Then catch the buffer and return it.

Let me know if you have questions!

Comment: Now that is truly great, i can't thank you enough!

Comment: I added the custom shortcode to my functions.php and my custom page template contains the HTML part with the embeded shortcodes.

Everything seems to work properly, except for the excerpt. The content is not displaying, just the title and the Read More link.

Comment: @Sniffles quick sanity check, are you passing `$content` via the shortcode or does the `$post` have an excerpt? what does your shortcode call look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I've just copied and pasted the code above (the one where it's saying "Here is how you write the shortcode* into my functions.php

Next i pasted the HTML part into my custom page template, called landingpage.php

Comment: The Title and the "Read More" link are displayed, but only that. Actually i wouldn't even need that, only the content of the posts is enough. Thanks!

Comment: K, given that, I'm guessing the code is working as expected, just both `$content` and `$post->post_excerpt` happen to be empty.  Since you said you don't need that anyway go ahead and replace that part with `<?= get_the_content(null, false, $post) ?>` to get the post content.

Comment: Excellent, that's working perfectly, thank you so much!
Just out of curiosity; you mentioned that `$content` and `$post->post_excerpt` are probably empty. Where should i put the content for it to work? The posts with the specifiied IDs have a content, which was added through wordpress backend, as usual. I'm sorry for all the questions... wont bother you after this anymore. Thank you so much again!

Comment: It's no problem, I'm thinking that's what this website is for. To your question, I think the fact that `$content` is a generic term, we're probably mixing context. $content in the context of a shortcode is what get's put inside the shortcode tag by the user `[some_tag]some user content[/some_tag]`. "some user content" gets passed to the shortcode callback as the second parameter (arbitrarily named $content). Once inside the callback we are querying a $post which has it's own context for content. That context, `$post->post_content`, is the texted saved to the post through the admin.

Comment: My code was saying if the user passed content via the shortcode, display that. If not, fallback to display the queried post's (via the post_id passed by the user) excerpt. However, it's very possible both of those are blank. I was doing a simple example of a shortcode, I wasn't worrying too much about what that shorcode was doing as long as you could get the gist of how you could use it in your situation. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Then i thin i understood it right. 

I made a test, so i opened the post with the ID 56 and entered this:

`[custom_landingpage]test content[/custom_landingpage]`, but the result is still empty. Btw. i changed the shortcode name to "custom_landingpage"

Comment: Hi again. I was just wondering if you got to test it again? I still can't get a content by using the shortcode. I entered this into my post with the ID 56:

`[custom_landingpage]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.[/custom_landingpage]`

But still nothing. Text which is entered outside of the shortcode isn't displayed as well.

Comment: Now, if a add an excerpt to the text in the post, that content shows up. But it's also displaying the shortcode closing tag [/custom_landingpage]. Looks like it's not processing the shortcode itself

Comment: It works for me so there might be something else in your code. Are you still validating the post_id in your shortocde `if (empty($atts['post_id']) || empty($post = get_post($atts['post_id']))) { return ''; /* return nothing, a proper post_id was not passed by the user */ }`? Because that would look like the shortcode isn't processing if you don't pass it a valid `post_id`.  You could return a message that says `return 'post_id is missing';` for debugging purposes.

Comment: Actually, you might want to mark my original answer as accepted and create a new code review for this latest issue. I think that would be best. Once you do that, post the link to the new question and we can debug over in that ticket, since this is a different scope than the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi again, here is the new post i created https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244996/wordpress-troubleshooting-of-custom-shortcode-where-no-content-is-displayed

Comment: Hi @Sniffles thanks! but the link is a 404 for me. let me know.

Comment: Hi @Phil; thanks so much for getting back to me. I had to move the post to Stack overflow. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730634/wordpress-troubleshooting-of-custom-shortcode-where-no-content-is-displayed

Comment: Awesome, thanks, posted comment there. I think one thing I'd I like to clear up is the line giving you trouble `<?= $content ?: $post->post_excerpt ?>` was actually meant to show the flexibility in a shortcode. In other words, you can pass content directly from a call to the shortcode and/or get data from the post and display it, or you can do both as one as a fallback to the other. However, in a instructional sense its fine, but in a real world scenario is probably isn't what you want and I think there is where the confusion is. Translating from a tutorial example to a real world use case.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an improvement, but I would recommend a few additional changes as well.

```php
<?php global $post; ?>

<div class="col kb_landing_left">
    <?php
    $post = get_post(56);
    setup_postdata($post);
    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'page');
    ?>
</div>
<div class="col -sm-6">
    <?php foreach ([1, 3, 2] as $post_id) : ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col kb_landing_right">
                <?php
                $post = get_post($post_id);
                setup_postdata($post);
                get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'page');
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php
// Reset back to the original post
$post = get_queried_object();
setup_postdata($post);
?>
```

Since you're new to PHP here are some notes on PHP specifically

- you only need to get the `global` variable once. Once a global variable is pulled in, it exists for the entire scope (whatever that scope happens to be).
- if your column code is the same it should be in a foreach loop

Some WordPress stuff

- `get_template_part` should only accept two parameters $slug and $name, maybe you meant `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' . get_post_format() )` possibly?
- changing the global $post will typically cause a lot of problems down the line, so I would not do that unless you're certain it needs to be done. I would recommend something like a WordPress shortcode or PHP function that handles your template for non-current post data. Only use get_template_part for calling templates for the currently queried post.
- if you do change the global $post, you'll (typically) need to reset it back to the original value because the rest of the (WordPress) code is dependent on it.

Please let me know if you're interested in using a WordPress shortcode for your columns.

Hope that helps!

**Edit:** As a side note, it looks like your html is malformed and a little bit different from the init question. Can you please check that as well. Also, please let me know if you're interested in using WordPress shortcodes. We can certainly optimize more, as we can write a little extra something today to will provide us a lot of value in the future. If WordPress is something you're never going to come back to again, then these micro-optimizes are not worth while. If this is something you plan to stick we, then it would be a good idea to take things a bit further. Thanks!

Comment: Again, thanks so much!

Yes, i would be very intrested in using the shortcodes as well, because I'm indeed planning to use wordpress on a long term.

Comment: I edited the code, it was wrongly pasted. But your code works perfectly alreday!

Comment: Awesome, glad I can help! Could you please mark the question as 'Accepted'. And if you need anything else feel free to ask. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, just did so.If you could give me some further advice about the shortcodes, that would be amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Of course, what is your current knowledge about WordPress shortcodes? https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API Are you familiar with what they are, or never heard of them until just now?

Comment: Perfect, i know a little something about them. I created one myself a few weeks ago, but just for testing.

Comment: K, good. Simply put they are just a formalized way to call functions with arguments in string form. Idea being someone who doesn't have access to the code (or doesn't know how to code) can put this little snippet (shortcode) into the WYSIWYG/Gutenberg/etc and it will display the result of a dynamic template via the arguments ($atts) that get passed. I'll go ahead and mock up an example using your code. I'll just need a moment as I'm wrapping up some other things right now.

Comment: You're amazing!!!!